# loop throught an object and return a array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

How can I loop over this object(data) and return a an array of object (output) just like this. basically with these specific properties and value

```
data = {
"model-10389": 164703,
"model-10388": 164704,
"model-10387": 164705,
}


const output  = [
{
  modelId : 10389,
 id : 164703
},
{
  modelId : 10388,
  id : 164704
},
{
  modelId : 10387,
  id : 164705
},
]
```

this is what I have now

```
Object.keys(data).map(function(key, index) {
 console.log(data[key])
});
```

or this

```
for (const property in data) {
console.log(`${property}: ${data[property]}`);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you figured out how to iterate over that object? Split your problem up into small steps and solve it one step at a time.

Comment: well I mapped through the object. I just updated the question

Comment: Don't change your question like that.

Comment: ___Again___, don't change your question like that. You're changing the premise of the question, invalidating the answers. There's absolutely nothing sensitive about a bunch of numbers. There's no reason to remove those. And even ___if___ you absolutely had to get rid of those exact values, there are better ways than just breaking the question and answers.

Answer (score 5):

Split the problem up into small parts:

1. Get all ["entries"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the source object.
2. These entries need to be transformed, we can use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for that
3. Every entry is an `[key, value]` array, we can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the `.map` for easy access.
4. For the `modelId`, we need to [`.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the key, and get the part behind the `-`, then [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) as a number.
5. The `id` is just the value.

```js
const data = { "model-10389": 164703, "model-10388": 164704, "model-10387": 164705 };

const result = Object.entries(data)
  .map(([key, value]) => ({
    modelId: parseInt(key.split('-')[1], 10),
    id: value
  }));

console.log(result);
```

A slightly faster alternative to the `split`, id to use a regex to extract ids:

```
modelId: parseInt(key.match(/\d+/)[0], 10),
```

However, if we're going to go as far as we can to optimize this transform, we're going to have to make a few more changes:

- Unary `+` instead of `parseInt`.
- `for in` loop instead of `Object.entries` and `.map`.
- Regex instead of `.split`

That'll get you:

```js
const data = { "model-10389": 164703, "model-10388": 164704, "model-10387": 164705 };

const result = [];
for (let key in data) {
  result.push({
    modelId: +key.match(/\d+/)[0],
    id: data[key]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you for the step by step explaination. Anw suggestion though without using the parseInt and the split ?

Comment: the split methods will divide the string in ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array. This means that it will create an array at every iteration. how do we avoid this ? is there an alternative to split ?

Comment: No, if you want only part of that string, `split` is your best approach, @maria. It is not a heavy operation...

Comment: But if there s a lot of data it will be an heavy operation. That is why I'm looking for an alternative

Comment: It will only be significant if we're talking millions of rows of data, @maria.

Comment: Well it is relevant actually in my case

Comment: @maria I've added some alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `Object.entries` with object destructuring, short object literal syntax and unary `+` for conversion to number:

```js
const data = {"model-10389": 164703,  "model-10388": 164704,  "model-10387": 164705};

const output = Object.entries(data).map(([key, id]) => ({
    modelId: +key.replace(/.*-/, ""),
    id
}));

console.log(output);
```

Comment: the split methods will divide the string in ordered list of substrings, puts these substrings into an array, and returns the array. This means that it will create an array at every iteration. how do we avoid this ? is there an alternative to split ?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about that, but it can also be done with `indexOf` or a `replace` with regex. I updated my answer with that latter idea.

Answer (score 0):

If the key(model-*) in data doesn't change, then you can use `substring()` with the index.

```js
const data = {
  "model-10389": 164703,
  "model-10388": 164704,
  "model-10387": 164705
}

const result = Object.entries(data)
                .map(([key, value]) => ({
                  modelId: +key.substring(6),
                  id: value
                }));
                
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That appears to be slower than the regex example I found